# Display Pageviewcontroller using storyboard segue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I have pageviewcontroller which i want to display and in this project using storyboard and segue

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Paper" ofType:@"pdf"];
PageViewController *page = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];
//[self presentViewController:page animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

If i use this statement

```
//[self presentViewController:page animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

then it doesn't display navigation bar and backbarbuttonitem

and when i remove this statement

```
 //[self presentViewController:page animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

then it doesn't display pageviewcontroller using curl effect transition for turning page over only it displays navigation bar and backbarbuttonitem.

and when i replace this statement

```
//[self presentViewController:page animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

with this statement

```
[self.view addSubview:page.view];
```

then it displays pageviewcontroller but doesn't turn page over at all.

Please help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you trying to present the PageViewController modally or push it on a navigation stack? Or are you using a custom segue to present the PageViewController?

Answer (score 1):

I think I see your issue. Since you have the segue set up in the storyboard, you don't have to call presentViewController. I think what you actually want to do in the prepareForSegue function:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[PageViewController class]]) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Paper" ofType:@"pdf"];
        PageViewController *page = (PageViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [page initWithPDFAtPath:path];
    }
}
```

Also, if the push segue is not built into the storyboard, you should be able to use your current code with one modification:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Paper" ofType:@"pdf"];
PageViewController *page = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:page animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But in preparefor segue i had PDFViewController *pdfviewController = [segue destinationViewController]; and if i add your lines then i get this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PDFViewController initWithPDFAtPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Ok, in that case you may need to determine if segue.destinationViewController is a PageViewController before you perform the logic. See my updated answer.

Comment: Do you have any other segues from your main view controller other than to the PageViewController? If not, you might need to make sure that the Class property in your storyboard for the page view is set to PageViewController and not UIViewController (or other).